# The Framework Tiles from SP-Starter-Kit is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts

I pulled the tiles out of the starter kit here, https://github.com/eoverfield/sp-starter-kit. I get NO errors when I do `npm install` and run `gulp serve`.

Everything works fine locally, but when I package the `.sppkg`, I come up with the error below:

ERROR message when I put it in SPO:

[image]

NPM and Node Version:

[image]

I think it has to do with the versioning of my NPM and Node?

Or maybe the `launch.json` needs to have the directory rather than the `localhost:4321`?

I am lost and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below commands in your package folder:

- `npm install`
- `npm install @pnp/spfx-property-controls --save --save-exact`
- `gulp serve`
- `gulp trust-dev-cert`

Then while packaging your solution run below commands:

- `gulp build`
- `gulp bundle --ship`
- `gulp package-solution --ship`

**official documentation**: [Host your client-side web part from Office 365 CDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn).

Comment: Is dependency of `@pnp/spfx-property-controls` is added in your `package.json` file??

Comment: It was not; maybe that did it. I followed the packaging commands and it works! Before I did not build and bundle before I packaged the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you run locally it run without error because all file are run from local but upload package (i.e. sppkg), still your file are resides locally. If you read error it is specifying that local server is not running.

Kindly follow

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn

above documentation which will show you how to upload webpart depended files to cdn or on SharePoint Online.